# Package serverless python service with individually packaged functions but shared code

Tags: python, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

Files from the utils folder are not included in the package when individually packaging with serverless-python-requirements plugin.

In my Serverless.com AWS Python project I have the following folder structure:

```
.
├── serverless.yml
├── generate_features
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── generate_features.py
├── requirements.txt
├── utils
│   ├── utility.py
│   └── additional_code.py
│   
:
```

The relevant section of my serverless.yml looks as follows

```
package:
  individually: true

functions:
  generate-features:
    handler: generate_features.handler
    module: generate_features
    timeout: 400

...
```

I would not include everything that is in the utils folder with each individually packaged function (there are more than one and they share some code).

Unfortunately when I use the serverless-python-requirements it appears that it won't let me do that. It only includes whatever is in the module directory. I would basically like to add additional modules though.

Any ideas? Am I not seeing some obvious way to include `utils/`? adding

```
package:
  include:
    - utils/**
```

at the function level unfortunately doesn't seem to work.

Thx